# vb.net my click excutes ahead by one record

Tags: database, vb.net

So I put code in the next button, and when I run it, it displays the first one right because it's in the form load, but when I click the next button it skips and shows the record behind by one.

here is the code:

```
Private Sub EnrollmentForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'PROJECT22DataSet.Student' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.StudentTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PROJECT22DataSet.Student)

    Try
        Dim Query As String
        Dim DataReader As OdbcDataReader
        Dim Command As New OdbcCommand

        dc.Open()
        Query = "SELECT Classname FROM Enroll WHERE STUNUM = (SELECT SID FROM Student WHERE SID = ?);"
        '"SELECT FROM EVENT WHERE ORG_ID = ?"
        'Command.Paramenters.AddWithValue("ORG_ID", Combox.
        Command.Connection = dc
        Command.CommandText = Query
        'Data comes from the dropbox box, then performs the subquery to gain the org id. Then queries all the events for that org_id
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SID", SIDTextBox.Text.ToString)

        DataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()
        ListBoxClassNames.Items.Clear()

        While DataReader.Read()
            ListBoxClassNames.Items.Add(DataReader("Classname"))
            '  Label_description.Text = (DataReader("Event_Description"))

        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    Finally
        dc.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see where you are incremementing the variable in order to get the next record. I think the most likely scenario is that you're incrementing before you retrieve the record when you should be incrementing afterwards. This can be fixed by either incrementing afterwards or changing your code flow so that it needs to be incremented first (depending on the situation),

Comment: Can you post the code for your Next button click handler?